# Reader Writer implementation in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I was trying to implement a reader-writer using notify and wait. But i think I'm stuck.
My sequence goes like this.
`RRRRRRRRRRWWWWWWWWW` This happens if the main start with reader invoked first.
   Or
`WWWWWWWRRRRRRRRRRR`.  This happens if the main start with the writer invoked first.
Looks like reads notify isn't working at all. Writer thread never goes into execution.

If i make while loop in run method to run infinite then it's just 
`RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR........`. No chance for the writer to write.
Can you have a look at this?

DATA CLASS

```
public class Data {
    private int q ;
    private boolean isAnyOneReading;

    public Data() {
    }

    public  void readQ() {
        synchronized (this){
            isAnyOneReading = true;
            System.out.println("Read start "+q);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        synchronized (this){
            isAnyOneReading = false;
            System.out.println("Read end "+q);
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void writeQ(int q) {
        System.out.println(isAnyOneReading);
        while (isAnyOneReading){
            try{
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Done");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Write start "+q);
        this.q = q;
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        System.out.println("Write end "+q);
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

READER CLASS

```
public class Reader implements  Runnable {
    private Data data;
    private Thread readerThread;


    public Reader(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
        readerThread = new Thread(this, "ReaderThread");
    }


    void startThread(){
        readerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0 ;
        while (i != 5){
            data.readQ();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

WRITER CLASS

```
public class Writer  implements  Runnable{
    private Data data;
    private Thread writerThread;

    public Writer(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
        writerThread = new Thread(this,"WriterThread," );
    }

    void startThread(){
        writerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i = 0 ;
        int j = 0 ;
        while (j != 5){
            data.writeQ(i++);
           // i++;
           j++;
        }
    }
}
```

MAIN CLASS

```
public class ReaderWriterDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Data data = new Data();
        Reader reader = new Reader(data);
        Writer writer = new Writer(data);

        reader.startThread();
        writer.startThread();



    }
}
```

Comment: You should make isAnyoneReading volatile, although there may be other issues, I haven’t run your code.

Comment: @tgdavies Didn't work. Reader dominates the execution and it's RRRRRRRRR..... till I  end it by `CTRL+C`.

Comment: @tgdavies, Why would you expect `volatile` to make any difference? The threads always are `synchronized` on the `Data` instance when they access the `isAnyoneReading` variable.

Comment: Good point @SolomonSlow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the Thread.sleep from Data class. 
And add Thread.sleep in run methods like so. (pasting one example):

```
 @Override
public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i != 5) {
        data.readQ();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read's notifyAll() works, but it seems that read() re-called again and changes isAnyOneReading's value prior to any other action in write(). That's why check fails and write() starts waiting again. As Danny Fried suggested moving Thread.sleep() to the run methods will help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple case of starvation. Consider your writer's main loop:

```
    while (j != 5){
        data.writeQ(i++);
       // i++;
       j++;
    }
```

`data.writeQ()` is a `synchronized` method: The very last thing it does before it returns is to unlock the lock. The very first thing it does on the next call is to re-lock the lock. Not much happens in-between--increment and test a local variable is all.

Java `synchronized` locks are not *fair*. (i.e., when a lock becomes available, the system does *not* guarantee that the winner will be the thread that's been waiting the longest.) In fact, it may be be the *opposite* of fair: The OS may try to maximize efficient use of the CPU(s) by always choosing the thread that's easiest to wake up.

When the writer comes back to call `data.writeQ()` on each subsequent iteration, it may be that the OS has not even have *started* to wake up the reader, and it simply lets the writer enter the `synchronized` block again.

---

Same thing happens with your reader.  The code is a bit more complicated, but just like in the writer, the very last thing that `data.readQ()` does before returning is to unlock the lock, and the very first thing that it does on the next call is to lock it again.

---

Brute force solution:  replace the `synchronized` blocks with a [*fair* `ReentrantLock` object.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#%3Cinit%3E(boolean))

Alternate solution, which is more typical of how many programs actually work: Have the threads do *something else* (e.g., have them do some I/O) in between calls to the locked function, thereby giving the other threads a chance to get in and use the locked resource.